# Create custom FormControl with Validators

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I’ve created a component (AComponent) which uses Material design  and I would like to use it as formControl in my Reactive Form (in the AppComponent). 
I’ve implemented `ControlValueAccessor` in this component (AComponent).

```
export class AComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  fm = new FormControl();

  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {
    ngControl.valueAccessor = this;

    this.fm.valueChanges.subscribe(v => {
      this.onChange(v);
    })
  }

  onChange = (_: any) => {}
  onTouched = () => {}

  writeValue(obj: any) {
    this.fm.setValue(obj);
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

}
```

I can set `Validators.required` for this component (in the AppComponent)

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      control: ['', Validators.required],
      controlOne: ['', Validators.required]
    })

    this.formGroup.statusChanges
      .subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

and it affects the whole form. (you can see on the console: invalid when ACompnent is invalid).

But the problem is I cannot force AComponent to look like invalid (red input) in case when it is invalid.
It looks like inner formControl (in the AComponent) doesn’t get `Validators.required` from AppComponent.

[image]

**The question is**: How can I set validators to AComponent in an elegant way?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmab64)

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://itnext.io/creating-a-custom-form-field-control-compatible-with-reactive-forms-and-angular-material-cf195905b451), doing exactly what you need (hint: search for "required" on that page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE** when we create a custom form control, Angular add ng-invalid ng-touched to our component. So, in general we change the apparence of our control using .css

```
.ng-invalid.ng-touched
{
color:red;
}
```

The problem is that we want change the aparence of a mat-input inside our custom form control. So we need know when is invalid our control.

in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxyvea?file=src%2Fapp%2Fa%2Fa.component.ts) you has your custom Form Control.

The key is know when your custom Form Control is invalid. For this, whe can inject ngControl. It's necesary using inject to avoid circular dependency. So, our constructor it's like

```
constructor(public injector: Injector) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);
    this.fm.valueChanges.subscribe(v => {
      this.onChange(v);
    })
  }
```

Well, we know when the custom control is valid, touched,pristine...

We are going to defined a .css like

```
.customError,.custom
{
  display:inline-block;
}
.customError .mat-form-field-empty.mat-form-field-label {
    color: red!important;
}
.customError .mat-form-field-underline {
    background-color: red!important;
}
```

And use ViewEncapsulation.None in our component. ViewEncapsulation.None makes the .css are in all the aplication. It's the reason because we add the class ".customError" before .mat-form-field-empty.mat-form-field-label and mat-form-field-underline. Else ALL our mat-components looks like has error.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-a',
   templateUrl: './a.component.html',
   styleUrls: [ './a.component.css' ],
   encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None,
   providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => AComponent),
    multi: true
   }]
})
```

After this, we use [ngClass] to add the classes

```
<div class="custom" 
    [ngClass]="{'customError':ngControl.invalid && ngControl.touched}" >

  <mat-form-field 
      [color]="ngControl.invalid && ngControl.touched?'warn':null" >
     <input matInput  placeholder="Some value" [formControl]="fm" (blur)="onTouched()">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

See that we use the property [color] in the mat-form-field to make the ripple underline becomes red too and how we use (blur) to mark as touched the control

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide NG_VALIDATORS

https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/angular-2-custom-form-control-with-validation-json-input-2b4cf9bc2d73

Answer (score 0):

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
        multi: true
    },
    {
        provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
        multi: true
    }  
]
```

You may also opt to set the ng-error classes with @Hostbinding